# How to check if a string has a specific format in Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, format

So my code should process lines and see if a line is a coordinate

```
"x y z"
```

example coordinate:

```
1.500 -6.002 0.007
```

with numbers representing the symbols and if so, I will process said line but if not, I'll leave it untouched. I gathered that re would be the right tool but I'm too new to know-how based on the different scenarios that have already happened in the past.

Comment: Can I add a float check to that if the symbol inbetween the coordinate floats is " " instead of ";"? (I'm a bit sleep, sorry about that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are not the best choice to see if a number is a float or not. It's complicated, given all the possible forms a valid floating point number can take and may take in the future versions of Python.

So it's much better to *try* to convert it and see if Python can do it, trap the exception if it can't.

I would do this like below:

```
def check_line(line_coord):
    try:
        return len([float(x) for x in line_coord.split()])==3
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

- create a list comprehension with float conversion on the line split according to spaces
- check if length of the list is equal to 3: return `True` if OK
- protect that by a `ValueError` exception, return `False` if exception caught

testing:

```
print(check_line("10 4.5dd 5.6"))  # bogus float in 2nd position
print(check_line("10 5.6"))  # only 2 fields
print(check_line("10 -40 5.6")) # 3 fields, all floats

False
False
True
```

EDIT: this above only *checks* if the values are here. Dawg suggested a way to return the triplet or `None` if error, like this:

```
def check_line(line_coord):
    try:
        x,y,z = map(float,line_coord.split())
        return x,y,z
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

(`map` is faster because it won't create a temporary list). with the same test as before we get:

```
None
None
(10.0, -40.0, 5.6)
```

Comment: You can do `try: x,y,z=map(float, line.split()); return x,y,z; except ValueError: return None`